# How to compare the user who is logged in with all existing users in a database system?

Tags: php, mysql, recommendation-engine

Now I'm building a system like social media. And it has feature to give recommendation user based of the result of calculate the similarity between user who is logged in with all existing users in database system. And the highest similarity will be show and be a recommendation for user who is logged in to become friend in system. Nah, now I use 3 users for testing my program and my pearson's correlation formula. Everything's going well. But if there's just 3 users in system, I can use this code for showing the result of calculation :

```
$u2=$u[1];
$u3=$u[2];
$sim1_2=similarity($u1,$u2);
$sim1_3=similarity($u1,$u3);
echo "<br>sim 1-2 ".$sim1_2;
echo "<br>sim 1-3 ".$sim1_3;
?>
```

where is `$u1` refers to user who is logged in. But if I want to show all result of comparing the user who logged in with all existing users in database, how? Because we can't predict how many users will be registered in my system later. So, how is the best way to compare user who logged in with all existing users in database? Thankyou in advance for your help.

Comment: Make a flag in your database .i.e in your registration table or make a reference for another table called tblLogin and use it.
If user is logged in set the flag to X and if not logged(logged out) keep it as null.
Use this flag to show active users.

Comment: @sumeet Sorry I didn't get that. All users who is registered in database that I mean. Not active user, so can I replace the "array" thing like [1] & [2] with another? Maybe function which can compare user who logged in with all existing users in database.

Comment: not sure if `similarity` is something you wrote or from a library but the following might help you [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) or maybe [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)?

Comment: @Class something I wrote and using Pearsons Correlation formula like I already wrote in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

You could just get an array or collection of all your users (or a batch of users) and simply iterate over it using a *for* or *foreach* loop, performing the similarity() function that you wrote. And if the similarity function returns a positive correlation result, add that into another array of that user's similarities.

Here is an example:

```
// Get users in any way you want. Let's assume that $users is an array
$users = getUsers();

//iterate over all users
foreach ($users as $user)
{   
    // Check if current user is similar to a user
    if (similarity($yourUser, $user))
    {
        // If the similarity function does not return false
        // then add that similarity result to an array.
        // We will assume that the similarity function returns
        // an associative array with keys such as 'username', 'id' etc
        $similarities[] = similarity($yourUser, $user);
    }
}

// Now we have a multi-dimensional array of similarity data that you can use in any way you want
// For example, lets display all usernames of the similar users
foreach ($similarities as $similarity)
{
    echo $similarity['username'];
}
```

This is just an example of how you could do this. Of course you could wrap that code into a function or a method of the user class depending on how you write and structure your code.

Obviously, this operation can take a long time if your system has a lot of users, so keep that in mind and be careful of when and how you run this code.